# Failed to enter to a docker container, created with kubernetes deployment

Tags: docker, deployment, kubernetes, containers, exec

With minikube i created simple deployment (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment) in the kubernetes. I'm sure that container must running , because kubernetes pod was started successfully and I can see container running in the Portainer. **But I just can't enter into the container!!**

(I always could do it with a simple pod, maybe with deployment something wrong)

```
$ docker exec -it 01a7c90b4267 /bin/bash
rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: dial unix /tmp/pty870274210/pty.sock: connect: connection refused
```

Also I found "Error syncing pod" in the container logs, but the container status is running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was caused by mounting to the minikubes' tmp folder `minikube mount $TMP:/tmp`. Without mounting I can exec the /bin/bash in the containers with no problems

Answer (score 1):

`bash` isn't available in your container. Have you tried with `sh`?

```
$ docker exec -ti 01a7c90b4267 sh
```

Also, if you're attaching to a running container within Kubernetes, you probably want to `kubectl exec` instead of `docker exec`:

```
$ kubectl exec -ti <pod_id> sh
```

Comment: I'm sure that as "/bin/bash" as "sh" must be available in the containers because i know what the docker images was used , and checked them on this commands. 
      `$kubectl exec -it cb-deployment-cdb9fdf5f-m6gv7 sh` also returns
        `rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: dial unix /tmp/pty757863663/pty.sock: connect: connection refused`